# Extending WiFi Range and streaming radio over wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, streaming

I stream radio over wifi to my Android phone because I live in a dead zone for over-the-air radio broadcasts. Currently I use the TuneIn app to stream radio to my phone.

In order to get wifi throughout my house, I have two identical Netgear WNR3500L wireless routers at opposite ends of the house. The primary router, next to my cable modem, is configured as a DHCP server. The other (secondary router) has DHCP turned off. A D-Link gigabit switch sits between the two routers.

When I listen to the radio stream on my phone (over wifi), after about two minutes of play time, the stream drops for 1-2 minutes. This repeats over and over. I suspect it may be caused by the phone switching between wifi signals from the two routers. Perhaps I shouldn't be using two routers at all but instead use one router and a range extender?

I think these are the possible solutions:

1. Put a single wifi router with the best range I can find in the center of the house.
2. Replace the secondary router with a range extender.
3. Keep my two routers as configured but instead of connecting them through a switch, plug the secondary router directly into the primary router.
4. Replace the TuneIn app on my Android phone with some other streaming app.

What is my best option to provide seamless wifi coverage throughout the house and hopefully allow me to stream radio without frequent, long interruptions?
Thanks!

Comment: When you say that your two routers and connected via a switch, is the switch connecting LAN ports on the router or WAN ports?

Comment: The switch is connected to LAN ports on the two routers.

Comment: Dont use two routers as your phone's Ip address changes repeatedly. You can disable DHCP on both and give a static IP to your phone (I donno how to).
Using range extender is best option.